# how to do a in depth permutation of some given letters in python?

Tags: python, permutation

So i have been trying to permutate some letters in python using the permutation library but i saw that it only return the given letters so that no letters are a duplicate, if i have the letters a, b and c the permutation will be as following.

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Now i have been trying for a way for a sort of more in depth way i guess so i have it like.

```
aaa 
aab 
aac 
aba 
abc
abc
aca
```

Is there a proper way to do this in python?
It could be that i'm wrong but that's the way i saw it.

**Edit after solve:**

People who wondered what i tried, i used the permutation part of the itertools library:

```
>>>print([x for x in itertools.permutations('1234')])
>>>[('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('1', '2', '4', '3'), ('1', '3', '2', '4') ... ]
```

Comment: It would be good if you could include the code of what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps  you want something like `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

print(list(product('abc', repeat = 3)))
# [('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c')]
```